# unable to send data from html div to flask server

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, flask

I have a div element with data. I want to pass the div to flask but I'm getting Badrequestkeyerror:400 bad request: keyerror:'yourdiv'

Please find the below html code:

```
<div id="rightdiv">
   item1,item2,item3,item4
   <form action="{{ (url_for('get_div_info') }}">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
</div>
<script>
   let yourdiv = document.getElementById("rightdiv").innerHTML;
   $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       url: '/divinfo',
       data: {'yourdiv': yourdiv},
       success: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
       },
       error{
           alert('something went wrong')
       }
   });
</script>

Flask endpoint

@app.route('/divinfo', methods=['POST'])
    def get_divinfo():
        divinfo = request.form['yourdiv']
        print(divinfo)
    return ('', 200)
```

Comment: Replace request.form with request.json

Comment: I've replaced but still getting error: typeerror "nonetype" object have no attribute __getitem__

Comment: Print request.data

Comment: `request.form.get('yourdiv')`

Comment: @Kruspe, it's returning 'None'